# CakePHP: why does format of data retrieved depend on which associated model is called

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a site with the usual sort of sellers, items and images. The models look like this:

```
class Seller extends AppModel {
   $hasMany = array('Item');    
   ... 
}

class Item extends AppModel {
   $belongsTo = array('Seller')
   $hasMany = array('Image');    
   ... 
}

class Image extends AppModel {
   $belongsTo = array('Item');
   ... 
}
```

My problem is that when I retrieve a list of Items, the data comes out in a **different format** depending on whether I am getting a list of all Items (to display to the public) in the ItemsController, or the details of a Seller and their Items in the SellersController.

Briefly `Item->find('all')` retrieves an array of

```
array(    'Item' => array( <item stuff> ),
          'Images' => array of array( <image stuff> ) );
```

whereas the `Seller->find('first', ...)` retrieves the Items as

```
array(    'Seller' => array( <seller stuff> ),
          'Item'   => array of array ( <item stuff>
                                       'Images' => array of array( <image stuff> ) );
```

In the 2nd case the `Images` element is nested within the `Item` part. Having the data formatted so differently makes it harder to re-use View code. Also my Item `afterFind()` won't work properly has problems when the Images bit isn't where it expects it to be.

**QUESTION**

Is there a simple way to prevent the `'Images'` part being nested within the `'Item'` part in the 2nd situation?

I am using Cake 2.4

**Formats in More Detail**

All items:

```
// in ItemsController.php
debug($this->Item->find('all'));
```

produces this:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Item' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'tom item 1',
        'seller_id' => '1'
    ),
    'Seller' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'tom'
    ),
    'Images' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'item_id' => '1',
            'path' => 'tom_1_1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'item_id' => '1',
            'path' => 'tom_1_2'
        )
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'Item' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'tom item 2',
        'seller_id' => '1'
    ),
    'Seller' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'tom'
    ),
    'Images' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'item_id' => '2',
            'path' => 'tom_2_1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'item_id' => '2',
            'path' => 'tom_2_2'
        )
    )
),
...
```

A single Seller + associated Items:

```
// In SellersController.php
debug($this->Seller->find('first', 
           array('conditions' => array('id' => $id), 'recursive' => 2)));
```

produces:

```
array(
'Seller' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'tom'
),
'Item' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'tom item 1',
        'seller_id' => '1',
        'Seller' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'tom'
        ),
  // Look! 'Images' is WITHIN 'Item !!!
        'Images' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'item_id' => '1',
                'path' => 'tom_1_1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'item_id' => '1',
                'path' => 'tom_1_2'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'tom item 2',
        'seller_id' => '1',
        'Seller' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'tom'
        ),
        'Images' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'item_id' => '2',
                'path' => 'tom_2_1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '4',
                'item_id' => '2',
                'path' => 'tom_2_2'
            )
        )
    ),
....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected and correct behavior as `Image` is not directly associated with `Seller`, but with `Item`.

Imagine, how would you determine the proper association when `Image` would be defined on the same level as `Item`? That would indicate an association with `Seller` which doesn't exist.

If you want a different structure, format it in your `afterFind` callback or wherever it's appropriate. However, I wouldn't recommend trying to work against the CakePHP standards. In case applicable, adapt your view code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me. If just wants to prevent Image to coming in 2nd case, try this

```
    $this->Seller->Item->unbindModel(array(
                        'hasMany' => array('Image')
    ));

           $result = $this->Seller->find('first', 
                 array('conditions' => array('id' => $id), 'recursive' => 2)));

           debug($result);
```